# Is it possible to change the URL of the popup window in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension which opens a popup window when the button is clicked:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

When the popup is loaded, I'd like it to redirect to a different URL, depending on the URL of the currently active browser tab.

I've tried `window.location.href = "http://example.com/"` in the popup, but just get a blank page.

I've tried loading the URL in an iframe which fills the whole popup window - which is fine - but  I need to close the popup window when the new URL calls window.close(), and this doesn't seem to be detectable when it's in an iframe.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If its a page you've created yourself then you can use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to send a message from the page in the iframe to the popup telling it to close.
The code you'll need in your files is...
**popup.js**

```
// change #frame to point at your iframe
var frame = document.querySelector('#frame');

window.addEventListener('message', closeWindow, false);

function closeWindow(event) {
    if(frame.src.indexOf(event.origin) === 0 && event.data == 'closeWindow') window.close();
}
```

**page in the iframe**

```
window.close = function() {
    window.parent.postMessage("closeWindow", window.parent.location.href);
}
```

To do it for any page that is in the iframe I couldn't think of any really clean way but this will do it.
Have a content script that runs on every url in all frames that checks to see if its in the iframe by checking its window.parent's url.
If it is in the iframe then over ride the window.close event with the above.
The window.close function we want to over ride is in the context of the page not content script so attach the script to the page.
Here's the code that does this...
**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "PopUp IFrame Parent Window Close",
  "description" : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673428/is-it-possible-to-change-the-url-of-the-popup-window-in-a-chrome-extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Test Closing IFrames parent if in popup",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
      "all_frames":true
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version":2
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="frame" src="http://localhost/windowclose.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function onLoad() {
    // change #frame to point at your iframe
    var frame = document.querySelector('#frame');

    window.addEventListener('message', closeWindow, false);

    function closeWindow(event) {
        if(frame.src.indexOf(event.origin) === 0 && event.data == 'closeWindow') window.close();
    }

}

window.addEventListener("load", onLoad)
```

**myscript.js**

```
hijackClose = function() {
    window.close = function() {
        window.parent.postMessage("closeWindow", window.parent.location.href);
    }
}

// Executing an anonymous script
function exec(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn + ')();';
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script); // run the script
    document.documentElement.removeChild(script); // clean up
}

if(window.parent && window.parent.location.href == chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')) {
    exec(hijackClose);
}
```

...now any page that calls window.close in the popups iframe will close the popup.